# Find needed package with tlmgr

Tags: packages

Is it possible to check which package do I need to install to get certain `.sty` file from `tlmgr` rather than googling it or going to CTAN?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$ tlmgr search --global --file cfr-lm.sty
tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
cfr-lm:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/cfr-lm/cfr-lm.sty
```

You should try this:

```
tlmgr --help
```