# Which package should I install to have the `fullpage.sty' file?

Tags: packages, tex-general

I am having the following error:

> File `fullpage.sty' not found.

Which package should I install? Or more general question: when some file is missing, how should I find the right package?

Comment: You should just install the [`fullpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage) using your distribution's package manager. Most likely this is covered under [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: Related: [Find needed package with tlmgr](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228169), but preferable to just install with the package manager, as Werner says.

Comment: Specific to this example, you could just use `\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}` (or `1.5cm`) in your preamble.

Comment: @Werner, I am using Ubuntu, and I installed fullpage package from the Ubuntu Software Center. It says that it is installed, however, when I type locate fullpage.sty in the terminal nothing appears?

Comment: @user3371223: Once the package is installed, you need to update TeX's "hash table". Run `mktexlsr` and try to recompile...

Comment: @Werner I did but it is the same. I will post another question for this. Thanks!

Comment: I solved this with `sudo tlmgr install preprint`