# How should I install the fullpage package under Ubuntu?

Tags: packages, installing, ubuntu, linux, tex-general

I am using Ubuntu Software Center. I found the package, click `Install` and it says that the package is installed. BUT when I tried to compile my .tex file it says

> LaTeX Error: File `fullpage.sty' not found.

When I typed in the terminal locate fullpage.sty nothing appears. When I typed  `apt-get install fullpage`, it gives the following error:

> E: Unable to locate package fullpage

I already did `mktexlsr`

What should I do in this case?

Comment: related [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016)

Comment: Seems to be in package `texlive-extra`

Comment: @Johannes_B How does it seem? I've been told that I have to use fullpage package? Here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228902/which-package-should-i-install-to-have-the-fullpage-sty-file?noredirect=1#comment540246_228902

Comment: texlive-packages are in meta-ubuntu packages. For example, apt-get doesn't show me `fullpage`. How does it seem? https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=oBPlVLqBCqaI8QfotoDwCw&gws_rd=ssl#q=ubuntu+fullpage+texlive But apparently, it is `texlive-latex-extra`; i messed that up.

Comment: @Johannes_B with texlive-extra I will get many packages, that I don't need. Is there a way to install only the package that contains fullpage.sty file?

Comment: Yep, get it from CTAN and unzip the file into you local `texmf`. [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)

Comment: Note that unless you are very short of space, you will make life much easier if you just install a full version of TeX Live. LaTeX will tell you *one package at a time* what you are missing.... This is not a fun way to spend time....

Comment: @cfr I checked already and I really miss just this one. However it says that it is in the context-modules package, which I don't know how to install.

Comment: Just do as suggested above and download it from CTAN if that's what you want to do. `fullpage` is not a ConTeXt module. (At least, certainly the one you want is not if you are using LaTeX.)

Comment: Note, you want `fullpage` which is part of `preprint` and not `context-fullpage`. (Unless you are using ConTeXt rather than LaTeX.)

Comment: I solved this with `sudo tlmgr install preprint`, it seems that's the package in question.

Answer (score 23):

Under Ubuntu, fullpage.sty is in the package texlive-latex-extra. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

Since the documentation is very big (327 MB), I installed it with

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra --no-install-recommends
```

Answer (score 3):

If you installed via apt-get, you should install packages via apt-get, which does not currently seem to have a `textlive-preprint` package so you'll need to use `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra`

If you happened to install otherwise such as MacTeX or a manual install on Linux, you can use `tlmgr` to install the small `preprint` package `sudo tlmgr install preprint`