# What makes up each TeX Live install-tl scheme?

Tags: texlive, installing, linux

Is there a way to find out what is installed in each of the possible installation schemes?

For example `basic scheme` just says `(plain and latex)` and `medium scheme` is `(small + more packages and languages)`, but I want a list of the actual LaTeX packages, CLI programs and files that are installed in my machine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there always is the hard way:

Several schemes are available on TeXLive, e.g.

basic, context, full, and more

They are described in these files

`https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/tlpsrc/scheme-basic.tlpsrc?view=markup
https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/tlpsrc/scheme-full.tlpsrc?view=markup
https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/tlpsrc/scheme-context.tlpsrc?view=markup
...`

These contain lists of dependent collections and packages, e.g. basic contains:

`depend collection-basic
depend collection-latex`

These, again, are files in the same folder:

`https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/tlpsrc/collection-basic.tlpsrc?view=markup
https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/tlpsrc/collection-latex.tlpsrc?view=markup`

Let's have a look at collection-basic:

`category Collection
shortdesc Essential programs and files
longdesc These files are regarded as basic for any TeX system, covering
longdesc plain TeX macros, Computer Modern fonts, and configuration for
longdesc common drivers; no LaTeX.
depend texlive.infra
depend amsfonts
depend bibtex
depend cm
depend colorprofiles
depend dvipdfmx
depend dvips
depend ec
depend enctex
depend etex
depend etex-pkg
depend glyphlist
depend graphics-def
depend hyph-utf8
depend hyphen-base
depend hyphenex
depend ifplatform
depend iftex
depend knuth-lib
depend knuth-local
depend kpathsea
depend lua-alt-getopt
depend luahbtex
depend luatex
depend makeindex
depend metafont
depend mflogo
depend mfware
depend modes
depend pdftex
depend plain
depend tex
depend tex-ini-files
depend texlive-common
depend texlive-docindex
depend texlive-en
depend texlive-msg-translations
depend texlive-scripts
depend tlshell
depend unicode-data
depend xdvi`

As you can see we are now at the package level. The packages have, again, their own files in the same location:

The package latex-bin.tlpsrc contains this line:

`https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/tlpsrc/latex-bin.tlpsrc?view=markup#l29
binpattern f bin/${ARCH}/pdflatex`

I am not an expert, but this looks to me like this package provides the pdflatex binary.

Resolving these dependencies is the job of the tlmgr-tool. According to [Find needed package with tlmgr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228169/find-needed-package-with-tlmgr)
you should be able to find any specific file you are looking for. I am not sure that there is a way to list all the files that a package provides. Please keep in mind that not all the files that a package provides are necessarily contained in the package (they could be generated upon installation).

The TeXLive Manual actually recommends to install **full**.

Comment: Full file list of 'apackage', installed or not: tlmgr info --list apackage This does not include generated files.